# how to mockup translateservice in jasmine unit testing of angular

Tags: karma-jasmine

LearningComponent > should create

> TypeError: this.translate.addLangs is not a function

Getting above error of my custom `component(LearningComponent)` while mocking up the Translate Service

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If you need addLangs method, then you need to add it to your Mock. For example:

```
class MockTranslateService {
    addLangs(langs: Array<string>): void {
    }
}
```

In your providers array:

```
            providers: [
                {provide: TranslateService, useClass: MockTranslateService}
            ]
```